Promise VS setInterval
Сразу скажу, прогаю как любитель, все не срочно и не критично.
Но хотелось бы сделать вот что. Разбираю свои небольшие математические скетчи на JS. Там вся анимация на setInterval/clearInterval.
Пример. Пусть:
isPlay - флаг проигрывания
delay - задержка
calculateNewState() - некие вычисления
showCanvas() - отображение
Вычисления достаточно долгие, отображение быстрое.
delay выбирается, чтобы в любом случае быть больше времени работы этих функций. И такой код:
function step()
{
    timerId = setInterval(function() {
        if (! isPlay) {
            clearInterval(timerId);
            return;
        }
        
        calculateNewState();
        showCanvas();
        
        if (! isPlay) clearInterval(timerId);
    },  delay);
}

Работает, при слишком малом delay запинается, но не критично.
И все же хочется сделать это грамотно и без запинок. Для этого, очевидно, и нужны промисы. В целом в них разобрался, сделал даже такой пример. Но как перейти от setInterval к промисам, никак не пойму ((
UPD
Уточняю формулировку. Выполнение calculateNewState() + showCanvas() должно занимать минимум delay сек. Если оно меньше - значит мы ждем оставшееся до delay время и начинаем новый цикл.
А если оно получается больше, тогда дожидаемся корректного завершения функций, и сразу начинаем новый цикл.
Думаю async-await для этого и созданы, но сложно найти примеры такого прямого применения.
Функции простые, вычисление массива и его отображение, внутри них нет ни интерфейса, ни setInterval ни async.

Возможно это ответ на ваш вопрос? Как я понял, вам надо зациклить выполнение функции и дожидаться выполнения всех промежуточных функций

@SwaD, да, весьма похоже, спасибо буду разбираться!

хз как там в JS и я вообще далек от анимаций, просто припоминаю что когда то в играх подобные циклы делали специально таймером чтобы держать стабильный ФПС. Условно, обновлять сцену 30 раз в секунду. Просто предположу, что здесь примерно по тем же причинам используется цикл.  Плюс, в зависимости от того, как сделана анимация, интервал в таймере может влиять или не влиять на её скорость. Если анимация зависит от интервала такмера, то тогда промисы наверное только сложнее эту связку сделают.

кстати, не знаю, поддержтвается ли асинхронное ожидание (await) в JS, если поддерживается, то тогда можно попробовать поменять таймер на асинхронный цикл, если всётаки надо как то уйти от таймера

@tym32167 await поддерживается в js. В первом комменте ссылка с примером(если интересно)

@SwaD ага, я припоминал что такое поддерживается, просто не помнил, оно в чистом JS или с в JS/TS с приседаниями ))

Для этого есть requestAnimationFrame, а для долгих вычислений WebWorker и OffscreenCanvas API. [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/OffscreenCanvas]


Но как перейти от setInterval к промисам, никак не пойму ((

Из приведенного можно сделать нечто такое...


let isPlay = true
const delay = 1000
step()
  .then(_ => console.log('Все'))
  .catch(console.log)
//
async function step() {
    while (isPlay) {
      await calculateNewState(2000),
      await showCanvas(1000)
      console.log('Шаг')
    }
}
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', _ => isPlay = false)
//
async function calculateNewState(delay) {
  await new Promise(res => setTimeout(_ => {
    console.log('calculateNewState завершен')
    res()
  }, delay));
}
//
async function showCanvas(delay) {
  await new Promise(res => setTimeout(_ => {
    console.log('showCanvas завершен')
    res()
  }, delay));
}
<button>Стоп</button>




Так работает, но у меня есть смутные сомнения, что этот код действительно ждет выполнения calculateNewState() и showCanvas(). Такое впечатление, что он ждет просто завершения setTimeout()

@DenisIvanov, я ведь про твои функции ничего не знаю... Вот пример без паузы. Именно с ожиданием завершения работы функций

ksa, да, так ближе! Функции можно считать самыми простыми - вычисление массива и его отображение. А про паузу уточнил в вопросе!

Ура, получилось, спасибо всем за советы!
async function sleep(delay) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            calculateNewState();
            showCanvas();
            resolve()
        }, delay);
    })
}

async function step(delay) {
    while (isPlay) {
        await sleep(delay)
    }
}

Отображается гораздо плавнее (к слову сказать, у меня delay около 40-50 мс),
жаль не получается GIF вставить.

У вас утечка памяти. Либо цикл, либо рекурсия, что-то одно тут явно лишнее.

.then(() => step(delay)) - эта строка не нужна

Исправил, память проверил, вроде все ок
